# Correct way to deal with a list of associated data items associated with several index values with pandas/pytables

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables, hdfstore

I was wondering what the correct way to deal with storing/reading through a list of items such as the following example dealing with a rockstar, where the list is known to hold a maximum number of values to hdf5:

```
Date_of_Birth
Bands[] - where the maximum number of bands is 10
Siblings[] - where the maximum number of siblings is 6
Date_of_Death
```

All of these would be column names.

One way I had considered, but turned out to give an error (`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`) was to have duplicate column names. Otherwise, what I could do is have `Bands 1`, `Bands 2` etc... but that would make retrieval and querying bothersome. Is there a better way? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: When using the numbered names, you can do something like `df.filter(like='Bands')` to select all 'Bands' rows.

Comment: Interesting... is there a way to query on all filtered? I only know of a way of querying item by item.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this where you actually want to list out each column of bands and siblings I would try to use a multiindex

lets say you have a dataframe you call df with these columns the call
`df.columns` spits out something like `Int64Index([dob, band_1, band_2], dtype='int64')`. You can reconstruct your index into something that will grab all the bands at once by doing this...

**edited found a way to do 'partial' MultiIndex**

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('dob',''),('bands','band_1'),('bands','band_2')])
```

Also a tip for constructing the list of tuples - You can add up a bunch of list comprehensions on the existing columns....

```
 [('band',each) for each in df.columns[df.columns>1].apply(lambda x: re.search("band",x)]
 #etc
```